# Clementine does not find song information for 30% of my library

Tags: music-player

I'm using the `automatic song information` feature a lot, but I have noticed that for many songs, it is not able to find any information.

Specifically, there are some duplicates in my library (I have no idea whether they're copies of one another or actually from different sources), and oftentimes, it finds information for one of them, but not the other. Existing metadata is equal and the file name is the same as well.

What could be the reason here? I'm clueless

Comment: Have you considered that maybe there isn't information about that song available to whatever clementine uses to identify them?

Comment: @Bralam well, as I said, there are duplicates with the same data, just in different directories. For one it works, for the other it doesn't. Also, the data is from music brainz and I have looked it up there manually - it exists

Comment: Are those duplicates the actual same song? Clementine may use something that reports different songs.

Comment: they are the same song, but may not be exactly the same file. Of course there has to be a difference, but I can't figure out what it is. Otherwise this would not be a question ;D